# Problema en query para Eliminar en SQL Oracle

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

Tengo un problema en cuanto a la eliminación de datos desde PHP en SQL ya que si quiero eliminar mis datos no realiza nada. El código es este:

```
if(@$_GET['q']== 'rmcap' ) {

    $PDF_ID=@$_GET['PDF_ID'];
    $name=@$_GET['NOMBRE_CAPACITACION'];

    $sql="DELETE FROM `capacitaciones` WHERE NOMBRE_CAPACITACION = '$name'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $sql="DELETE FROM `pdf_usuario` WHERE PDF_ID = '$PDF_ID'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    header("location:VerCapacitaciones.php");
}
```

Esa es la clase para poder hacer la eliminación y este es el código del botón que elimina:

```
echo '<td><a href="script.php?q=rmcap&qiz='.$nombre.' &pdf_id='.$pdf_id.'"onClick=\"javascript:return confirm(¿Estás seguro de eliminar?);\">Eliminar</a></td>';
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! los parametros no son los mismos que recibe la funcion (donde esta el nombre por ejemplo?) podrias agregar tambien algun tipo de control de errores

Answer (score 2):

Dado que en tu botón las variables GET se llama `qiz` y `pdf_id` ambas en **Minusculas**

En tu clase donde recibes los valores debería de ser así:

```
$PDF_ID=@$_GET['pdf_id'];
$name=@$_GET['qiz'];
```

Ambos nombre en minúsculas.

Y OJO en tu código tenias `$name=@$_GET['NOMBRE_CAPACITACION'];` pero la variable con nombre `NOMBRE_CAPACITACION` no existe en tu botón que elimina, por eso yo en mi código uso `qiz`, que según tu código es ahí donde guardas la variable `$nombre`

Otra observación, en tu botón que elimina hay un espacio entre los nombres de las variables y sus respectivos valores. debería de ser así:

```
echo '<td><a href="script.php?q=rmcap&qiz='.$nombre.'&pdf_id='.$pdf_id.' "onClick=\"javascript:return confirm(¿Estás seguro de eliminar?);\">Eliminar</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo veo así, creo que te has liado un poco con el paso de las variables desde el botón:

En el caso de las variables que pasas son erróneas ya que las variables que estas pasando son: `q`, `qiz` y `pdf_id`, estas variables las recibes en tu clase a través de la URL y debes cambiarlo ya que no estas recogiendo las mismas de forma correcta, quedaría así:

```
if(@$_GET['q']== 'rmcap' ) {

$PDF_ID=@$_GET['pdf_id'];
$name=@$_GET['qiz'];

$sql="DELETE FROM `capacitaciones` WHERE NOMBRE_CAPACITACION = '$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sql="DELETE FROM `pdf_usuario` WHERE PDF_ID = '$PDF_ID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
header("location:VerCapacitaciones.php");}
```

asi quedaria. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando a esto:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM `capacitaciones` WHERE NOMBRE_CAPACITACION = '" .$name. "'";
```

Comment: Procura siempre una explicación breve del por qué el código resuelve la pregunta